# How to intersect two binary images using MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, binary, intersection

I would like to do the following:

1. apply the sobel gradient to a binary image
2. apply the laplacian gradient to the the same binary image
3. intersect those two images in order to remove noise generated by the laplacian gradient output image ....

I have tried the following code in matlab:

```
a=imread('F:\Photos\projpics\plap.png');
b=imread('F:\Photos\projpics\psob.png');
c=bitand(a,b);

subplot(2,2,3), image(uint8(c)), title('Intersection');
subplot(2,2,1), image(uint8(a)), title('sobel');
subplot(2,2,2), image(uint8(b)), title('laplacian');
```

but it is showing the result as very similar to the image of the sobel gradient result... Is this normal? Am I doing something wrong? Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Where in this code did you apply Sobel\Laplacian edge detector filter ?

Comment: both the images which I have taken are resultants of sobel and laplacian gradients.The resultant is taken in c by applying bitand operator over two images...Is there any other way to find??I have tried with comparing the pixels of both the images for knowing similar pixels ,then also unable to do it..

Comment: Are they binary images? Laplacian filter does not create binary images, do you may have values almost everywhere. That would mean that you would get the other image (sobel) as a result of an and